# Meaning of <chrome extension> 'Has access to this site'?

Tags: privacy, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When browsing using chrome, if I hover over any of the extensions displayed in the top right of chrome browser, I see

> 'ADDON NAME Has access to this site'

What exactly can the developers of an addon see?

E.g. Does this mean they (i.e. the addon / devs who made the addon) see

- the url visited?
- Images looked at (say you're on facebook, can they see what you see as you scroll down the newsfeed?)
- Unencrypted data sent (e.g. if you submit a web form over http)?

Answer (score 1):

I looked into a similar permission of 'This can read and change data' and from what I have read, the extension(and potentially developers of that extension) would be able to see the pages, including the content, media and URL.

I would not take my answer as de facto though(it would be best if an extension dev or Google provided more insight into this topic), but I found an interesting article that goes into these scenarios further:
https://www.howtogeek.com/291095/why-do-chrome-extensions-need-all-your-data-on-the-websites-you-visit/

**I assume the worst at all times.
Be vigilant with your data, privacy and security at all times. No one cares about you except you.**

Other References:
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en